# Error remove over-representative sequences : TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: bioinformatics, genome

Hi I am running this python script to remove over-representative sequences from my fastq files, but I keep getting the error. I am new to bioinfomatics and have been following a fixed set of pipeline for sequence assembly. I wanted to remove over-representative sequences with this script

python /home/TranscriptomeAssemblyTools/RemoveFastqcOverrepSequenceReads.py -1 R1_1.fq -2 R1_2.fq
**Here is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "TranscriptomeAssemblyTools/RemoveFastqcOverrepSequenceReads.py", line 46, in
leftseqs=ParseFastqcLog(opts.l_fastqc)
File "TranscriptomeAssemblyTools/RemoveFastqcOverrepSequenceReads.py", line 33, in ParseFastqcLog
with open(fastqclog) as fp:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found**

- **Here is the script** :

```
                import sys
                import gzip
                from os.path import basename
                import argparse
                import re
                from itertools import izip,izip_longest

                def seqsmatch(overreplist,read):
                    flag=False
                    if overreplist!=[]:
                        for seq in overreplist:
                            if seq in read:
                                flag=True
                                break
                    return flag

                def get_input_streams(r1file,r2file):
                    if  r1file[-2:]=='gz':
                        r1handle=gzip.open(r1file,'rb')
                        r2handle=gzip.open(r2file,'rb')
                    else:
                        r1handle=open(r1file,'r')
                        r2handle=open(r2file,'r')

                    return r1handle,r2handle

                def FastqIterate(iterable,fillvalue=None):
                    "Grab one 4-line fastq read at a time"
                    args = [iter(iterable)] * 4
                    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args) 

                def ParseFastqcLog(fastqclog):    
                    with open(fastqclog) as fp:
                        for result in re.findall('Overrepresented sequences(.*?)END_MODULE', fp.read(), re.S):
                            seqs=([i.split('\t')[0] for i in result.split('\n')[2:-1]])
                    return seqs     

                if __name__=="__main__": 
                    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="options for removing reads with over-represented sequences")
                    parser.add_argument('-1','--left_reads',dest='leftreads',type=str,help='R1 fastq file')
                    parser.add_argument('-2','--right_reads',dest='rightreads',type=str,help='R2 fastq file')
                    parser.add_argument('-fql','--fastqc_left',dest='l_fastqc',type=str,help='fastqc text file for R1')
                    parser.add_argument('-fqr','--fastqc_right',dest='r_fastqc',type=str,help='fastqc text file for R2')
                    opts = parser.parse_args()

                    leftseqs=ParseFastqcLog(opts.l_fastqc)
                    rightseqs=ParseFastqcLog(opts.r_fastqc)

                    r1_out=open('rmoverrep_'+basename(opts.leftreads).replace('.gz',''),'w')
                    r2_out=open('rmoverrep_'+basename(opts.rightreads).replace('.gz',''),'w')

                    r1_stream,r2_stream=get_input_streams(opts.leftreads,opts.rightreads)

                    counter=0
                    failcounter=0

                    with r1_stream as f1, r2_stream as f2:
                        R1=FastqIterate(f1)
                        R2=FastqIterate(f2)
                        for entry in R1:
                            counter+=1
                            if counter%100000==0:
                                print "%s reads processed" % counter

                            head1,seq1,placeholder1,qual1=[i.strip() for i in entry]
                            head2,seq2,placeholder2,qual2=[j.strip() for j in R2.next()]

                            flagleft,flagright=seqsmatch(leftseqs,seq1),seqsmatch(rightseqs,seq2)

                            if True not in (flagleft,flagright):
                                r1_out.write('%s\n' % '\n'.join([head1,seq1,'+',qual1]))
                                r2_out.write('%s\n' % '\n'.join([head2,seq2,'+',qual2]))
                            else:
                                failcounter+=1


                        print 'total # of reads evaluated = %s' % counter
                        print 'number of reads retained = %s' % (counter-failcounter)
                        print 'number of PE reads filtered = %s' % failcounter


                r1_out.close()
                r2_out.close()
```

Comment: It looks like the code is not doing any control on its required input files. You should add some check on the command line parameters to be sure you got what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved it, I had the same error but now is running well. 
Hope this help

(1) Files we need:
usage: RemoveFastqcOverrepSequenceReads.py [-h] [-1 LEFTREADS] [-2 RIGHTREADS] [-fql L_FASTQC] [-fqr R_FASTQC

(2) Specify fastqc_data.text files that are in the fastqc output, unzip the output directory

'-fql','--fastqc_left',dest='l_fastqc',type=str,help='fastqc text file for R1'

'-fqr','--fastqc_right',dest='r_fastqc',type=str,help='fastqc text file for R2'

(3) Keep the reads and the fastqc_data text in the same directory

(4) Specify the path location before each file
 python RemoveFastqcOverrepSequenceReads.py 
-1 ./bicho.fq.1.gz -2./bicho.fq.2.gz 
-fql ./fastqc_data_bicho_1.txt -fqr ./fastqc_data_bicho_2.txt

(5) run! :)